# Is the space of absolutely continuous measures dense in the space of signed measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let's say we have $\mathbb{R}^n$ or a compactification of it and denote with $\overline{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ the space of measures that are absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it true that $\overline{\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)}$  is dense in the space of signed measures $\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Dense in what topology?

Comment: Given any real  Borel measure $\mu$ there exist absolutely continuous measures $\mu_n$ such that $\int fd\mu_n \to \int fdm$ for all bounded continuous functions $f$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes I meant this topology of convergence in measure. So can i say that $\mu_n(dx)=g_n(x)dx$ and $\int fg_ndx\rightarrow\int fd\mu$ for any $\mu\in\mathcal{M}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? Right? Do you know some strong reference where this is treated in a strong way?

Comment: This is quite easy if you use probability theory. For example if $X$ is any random variable , $Y$ is independent of $X$ with standard normal distribution then $X+\frac Y n \to X$ (a.s. hence ) in distribution .  The distribution of $X+\frac Y n $ is absolutely continuous.   Thus  the distribution of $X$ is the limit of a sequence of absolutely continuous distributions.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged your question with [functional-analysis] so a functional analytic answer might be appropriate.

Given a Banach space $X$, and any linear subspace $S$ of the topological dual $X'$ of $X$, one has that $S$ is dense in the weak$^*$ topology (i.e. the topology of pointwise convergence) iff the only vector $x$ in $X$ such that
$
x'(x) = 0,
$
for every $x'$ in $S$, is the zero vector itself.

Setting $X=C_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$, one has that $X'$ is the set of all finite signed Borel measures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if you let $S$ be the set of all absolutely continuous measures you get your answer as a corollary of the above result.

Comment: WOW. Can you give explicit reference for this general result? I didn't study functional analysis in this point of view. Maybe is something I've studied in another way not being aware of its consequences. And finally this means that the space of singular measures are something like Dedekind sections for real numbers? Very interesting!!

Comment: Check Corollary IV.3.14 in Conway's Functional Analysis book.  Some interpretation is necessary to apply this result to the present situation, so please do not hesitate to ask in case you have any questions.

Comment: Sorry but I think this does not work. Indeed take a function $f\in C_0(\mathbb{R})$ that is zero out of a zero measure set. The function is not zero. You can take a delta for example. Then by Riesz representation we have an integral representation of the dual i.e. $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\mu(dx)=0$. But $f\neq 0$. So I think you cannot apply this. But I was searching for something like this.

Comment: No such function exists. This is because the complement of a zero measure set is dense, and if a continuous function vanishes there, it must be zero.  A delta function is never continuous!