# Derivative of an integral with time dependent measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, borel-measures

Assume you have to deal with the following derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{a(t)}^{b(t)}f(t,x)\mu_t(dx),$$

for some properly regular function $f,a,b$ and where $\mu_t$ is a Borel measure for each time, possibly not absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue. The question is how can one explicit this: is there any "Leibniz integral rule style" theorem from measure theory dealing with this case?

Comment: You need strong hypothesis even to say that the integral exists and is differentiable. There is no Leibniz rule for this.

Comment: If $\mu_t(dx)=\phi (t)\mu (dx)$ for some nice function $\phi$ then you can write down the derivative but that is a very special case.

Comment: Thank you so much Kavi Rama Murthy. I think one can go a bit further on this. The space of measures that are absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue is dense in the space of signed measure. See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3877946/is-the-space-of-absolutely-continuous-measures-dense-in-the-space-of-signed-meas/3878095?noredirect=1#comment8014764_3878095. This means that if $\mu_t$ stays on this dense set for all $t$ one has: $\mu_t(dx)=\phi(x,t)dx$. And one can use the usual Leibniz Integral Rule there. How can this works with singular measures? I'm expecting it works also there

Comment: Absolutely continuous case is of course easy and it brings us back to usual Leibniz rule. I was ignoring that case since you said $\mu_t$ is not assumed to be  absolutely continuous. A doubt if there is any Leibniz rule in the singular case except in the special case I mentioned.